# Powershell replace exact string

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I want to replace a simple string "WEEK." (with a dot) in a text file with the string "TEST"

```
$LOG= "C:\FILE.TXT"
$A= "TEST"
(Get-Content $LOG) | Foreach { $_ -Replace "WEEK.", $A } | Set-Content $LOG;
```

The problem is that my file has this content:

```
WEEK_A WEEK.
```

And when I run my script the result is:

```
TESTA TEST
```

and the result that i want is:

```
WEEK_A TEST
```

I try with ^ "WEEK." and "^WEEK.$" but it not worked

Can you help me with the regexp? Thanks

====== EDIT ==================

Ok. I try with

```
$LOG= "C:\FILE.TXT"
$A= "TEST"
(Get-Content $LOG) | Foreach { $_ -Replace "WEEK\.", $A } | Set-Content $LOG;
```

and seems its works

Comment: Seems you have answered your own question

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this happened is because you have used pattern `WEEK.` The dot was a problem: in a regular expression world, the dot means "any character". That's why it was replacing both `WEEK_` and `WEEK.`.

When you have added backslash, then the dot was escaped ie. it lost it's special meaning. Thus making it work.